# ASP.net MVC form submission always calls GET action instead of POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in ASP.net MVC that looks like this:

```
<div class="x_content">

    <form id="elementEditForm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />


        ... my form fields....

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" form="elementEditForm" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And in the controller I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var e = getEditModel(id);
    return View("GenericElementEdittView", e);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, object evm, string returnUrl = null)
{
    log.Info(evm);

    return View();
}
```

My problem is that the `HttpPost` method is not called when I click the button to submit the form. Instead, the `HttpGet` method gets called every time, resulting in the page just reloading instead of submitting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GET` is the default method when none is specified.  Specify the `POST` method:

```
<form id="elementEditForm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks, for whatever reason I was assuming post was the default method when submitting... my fault. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing it. I prefer using HTML Helper for form because it visually gives more idea of what the form is supposed to do.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","<ControllerName>",FormMethod.Post, new {@id="elementEditForm", @class="form-horizontal form-label-left"}))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />


    ... my form fields....

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" form="elementEditForm" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```